# The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.2.0' was not found

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

I am using Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.3.7. I assume it is the latest update.

When I try to compile a basic .NET Core 2.2 console application:

[image]

...I get the following error:

```
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.2.0' was not found.
  - The following frameworks were found:
      1.0.1 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      2.0.9 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      2.1.11 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      2.1.12 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      2.1.13 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      3.0.0 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.

The .NET Core frameworks can be found at:
  - https://aka.ms/dotnet-download .
```

[image]

My understanding is that .NET Core 3.0 is backward compatible. Why Visual Studio installer installed all versions of .NET Core except 2.2?
How do I solve this problem?

Comment: when `3.0` framework is installed shouldn't you be able to build `.net core 2.2` application?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In my case was missing **x86 .NET Core 2.2.x Platform SDK** (Visual Studio .NET 16.4 + .NET Core 3.1 SDK ; xUnit Test Project).

You can try this:

1. Exist directory 2.2.x in: `C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App` ?
2. When no, try Download latest 2.2.x **SDK** for **x86 platform** from this URL: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2
3. **Install** and try ...
4. For **more** info about installed SDK and Runtime you can use command: `dotnet --info`

Comment: @Martin Thanks for the answer. But why it was looking under x86 folder when the machine where it is running is 64 bit.

Comment: This worked for me as well; I was getting this error from NUnit. @DeepakTekchandani I believe x86 is required because the IDE is 32-bit (yes, even 2019) and so extensions rely on 32-bit SDKs. (I could be mistaken though.)

Comment: This fixed my issue as well.

Comment: This solved my issue as well. I kept trying to install x64, which did not work as expected. Installing x86 worked as a charm.

Comment: @DeepakTekchandani I think that is because some .NET project package uses older 32-bit code ; 64 bit system can run both code: 32 and 64-bits. Solution was surprise in this case :)

Comment: This solution helped me too

Answer (score 83):

For whatever reason, .NET Core 2.2 is not installed by the ".NET Core cross-platform development" workload.

Open up the Visual Studio installer then go to the "Individual components" tab and you can install it from there:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did not help, had to install x86 .NET Core 2.2.x Platform SDK as described in below answer(https://stackoverflow.com/a/59189867/5699719)

Comment: Only had .net5 installed, did this and adding a .asmx reference worked.

Answer (score 4):

For those trying to deploy a file to a non-developer machine and you see this error, use the Project -> Publish option with a Folder Profile and update the settings to be "Deployment mode: Self-contained". Then "Publish" it.

This will embed the runtime into the .exe, making it much larger, but also simple to "just work" on a client machine.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can install x86 .NET Core 2.2.x Platform SDK as @Martin said.

If you do not need x86 version like me, you can also set

```xml
<PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
```

to

```xml
 <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
```

in both main project and test project 's .csproj file

to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Two options are to run the Visual Studio Update application to see if any missing requirements will be installed for you or to install the net core 2.2 SDK manually from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2 (or https://aka.ms/dotnet-download as mentioned in the error message).

Comment: This is the very latest upated visual studio 2019, confirmed by visual studio installer. Why Visual Studio installer installed all versions of netcore except 2.2?

Comment: 2.2 has reached its end of life and is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

This case in only applicable for already running app, and then you are trying to deploy a new release with new published files with updated version of dotnet.

if you are deploying on the same dotnet version but minor version is different for example current release is 7.0.0 and new update is 7.0.1

then ***dont update project_name.deps.json and project_name.runtimeconfig.json***

and update remaining changed dlls.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you are using VS Code, you can change the .csproj file in the `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>` tag.
Change it to the installed version, like `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp7.0</TargetFramework>`.

Answer (score -3):

.NET Core 2.2.0 is not supported anymore.
Waiting for the .NET 5